# adding discord app commands using @bot.tree.command

Tags: python, discord.py

so i wanted to add slash commands to my bot. i looked here (on stack) but i couldnt find the solution

```
@bot.tree.command(name = "test", description = "testing purposes only")
```

that didnt work unfortunatly.
The bot itself works, it boots up but the shash commands do not work
this is also my manual loader (yes i loaded the commands they still dont show up)

```
@bot.command()
async def bsync(ctx):
    print("sync command")
    if ctx.author.id == user id:
        await bot.tree.sync()
        await ctx.send('Command tree synced.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You must be the owner to use this command!')

@tree.command(name='sync', description='Owner only')
async def tsync(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.user.id == user id:
        await tree.sync()
        print('Command tree synced.')
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message('You must be the owner to use this command!')
```

does anybody know how to here make slash commands and can help me?

Comment: It takes time, global app commands can take up to 1-2h to sync.

Comment: by my experience you can see the slash commands as soon as you restarted discord after syncing.

Comment: You cannot use both prefix commands and slash commands, except for [hybrid commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.hybrid_command)

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding a slash command to your discord bot you have to remember to sync all the command the moment the bot activates.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.tree.sync()
    print("The bot is online")
```

Once the "The bot is online" text shows up in the console then reload the discord tab and try and run the command, it should work then.

You should also do `@bot.tree.command(name='sync', description='Owner only')` instead of just `@tree.command(name='sync', description='Owner only')`